# Variable namespaces in classes (Python3)

Tags: ros, python, ros2, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having difficulties using variable namespaces with python3 classes

Here's a snippet of code that I would think would work, but doesn't.

In the BasicNavigator class:

```
    self.namespace = ''

    self.localization_pose_sub = self.create_subscription(PoseWithCovarianceStamped,
                                                          self.namespace + '/amcl_pose',
                                                          self._amclPoseCallback,
                                                          amcl_pose_qos)
```

In main:

```
navigator = BasicNavigator()

navigator.namespace = "robot1"
```

This does not work, it does not recognize the **"robot1"** in the class.

Instead, if I remove the `self.namespace` and just write the topic name as such: `'robot1/amcl_pose'` it works, but I need to be able to have a variable amount of robots...

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398885/variable-namespaces-in-classes-(python3)/) by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2022-04-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2022-04-11**:
Very likely the subscription is getting created *before* `self.namespace` is being set to `robot1`. What if you made the constructor of `BasicNavigator` take in a namespace, so that you can do something like `self.namespace = namespace`?

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-04-11**:
As the previous comment said, you need to rearrange when you're setting the namespace and when the subscription is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, **abhishek47** and **aprotyas** for your comments.
It worked by creating a method with the namespace argument.

In BasicNavigor class:

```
def createSubscriptions(self, namespace):
    self.localization_pose_sub = self.create_subscription(PoseWithCovarianceStamped,
                                                          namespace + 'amcl_pose',
                                                          self._amclPoseCallback,
                                                          amcl_pose_qos)
```

And then I call this in main:

```
navigator = BasicNavigator()

namespace = "robot1"
navigator.createSubscriptions(namespace)
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you wanted me to try, but it works, so I'm happy :)

---

Originally posted by [WarTurtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/89469/warturtle/) with karma: 170 on 2022-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aprotyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/74476/aprotyas/) on 2022-04-13**:
Something along these lines, yes. Good to know that it worked!